# How to mod_rewrite a query parameter to a path folder name?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, query-string

I'm doing my first steps with `url-rewriting` and can't get the following to work:

In my application, a skin can be loaded by applying query parameter `?skin=some_id` to any page in the application. I want to change:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/anypage.html?skin=123
```

into:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/123/anypage.html
```

but I cannot get it to work.

This is what I currently have in my `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RRewriteRule (.*)/(.*)?app=(.*)$ %1/%3/%2 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Questions:**
This isn't working, so I would like to know what I'm doing wrong?

Also with the URL in effect, what is the URL the user enters? `http://www.mysite.com/123/anypage.html` which "maps" to `http://www.mysite.com/anypage.html?skin=123`?

And if I want to access the query parameter, do I have to extract it from the actual url (`?skin=...`) or from the rewritten URL?

Thanks for helping out!

**EDIT:**
So I have it sort of working doing it like this (helpful tester [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} skin=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^.*\.html /%1? [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect:

```
 www.some.com/index.html?skin=xyz   =>  www.some.com/xyz
```

Not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend going about skinning your application differently.  The way you have it now will create duplicate content issues with search engines because they will see the same content for each page on your site for every skin you have.

That is to say, `yoursite.com/dark/about.html` would be identical content to `yoursite.com/spring/about.html` so search engines may have a hard time deciding which version to use.  In addition, it seems like it will create extra work for linking to other pages on your site since you will have to create your links programmatically to use the proper path and skin.

I would just have a URL for activating a skin and store their preference in a cookie or in a session and skin the site based on the cookie/session value and only maintain one set of URLs.

Unless you really want the skin to be in the URL, I would shy away from using the URL or query string to indicate which skin to use.  Instead have it be a preference attached to an account or stored in a cookie.

Comment: hm. Good points. Right now I trigger a skin using `?skin=123`, but I'm not really happy with it and the folder variant seemed like something worth exploring. I have the skin (and configuration) attached to a server-side account plus storing it in a cookie. Problem is if all users have the same `www.mysite.com` link through which they want to access their skin, what means do I have to load the skin before logging in or setting a cookie if not through the url?

Comment: I would use a cookie to hold the skin, and also store it with their account.  This way, if they log in and choose a skin, you set the cookie with the preference.  Then when they log out, the cookie is still there so next time they come back you can use the skin from the cookie.  For setting the cookie, you can have a PHP file, say, setskin.php which when called like setskin.php?skin=dark the script sets the cookie, and optionally updates their account settings and redirects back to the previous page.  Does that make sense?

Comment: more or less :-) Last question: What if the skin is not related to the user logging in but to the page from which `www.mysite.com` is accessed from? So if a user goes on the site directly, default skin is loaded, but if he is coming from `www.abc.com`, skin `abc` is loaded? Currently, I'm doing it like that = the link on abc will be `www.mysite.com/index.html?app=abc` which will load the appropriate skin.

Comment: In that case, maybe instead of having the setskin.php script, you can have some global code that would recognize `app=abc` on any URL of your site.  Then you could still set the cookie and set the option in your code to use that skin on the initial request.  You could also get fancy with mod_rewrite and detect any request to your site with a skin in the URL, rewrite it to setskin.php?skin=blah&url=http://url_they_landed_on and then have setskin.php redirect to `url` if that URL is on your domain.

Comment: I'm playing around with your suggestion now and trying to rewrite to some nicer urls. Thanks for all the input!